# Angular passport login without reloading the website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, passport.js

in my Angular app you can configure several things, but only save then into a DB if you are logged in.
When configuring first and then logging in, the configuration gets lost due to the reload of the site. So you then do have to configure everything again in order to save it to the DB.

Is there a way to login without reloading the site?
I am using angular passport with local-login Strategy

```
app.post('/login/', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/#!/configure',
    failureRedirect: '/#!/login',
}));
```

Or is there no better way than saving everything in a angular-local-storage or Cookie?

Comment: Are you making API call??

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I am using a html form which performs a POST on /login  I guess the successRedirect does the reload

Comment: If you perform a `post` through a form, the default behaviour is for the page to reload. Rather, execute the `post` with AJAX.